# Getting error while parameterize in pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I have CalculateNoOfDays.py which is calculating no of days in between the dates.
Sample code:

import pytest
`enter code here`class Date:
def **init**(self, d, m, y):
self.d = d
self.m = m
self.y = y

monthDays = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30,
31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]

def countLeapYears(d):
years = d.y

```
if d.m <= 2:
    years -= 1

return int(years / 4) - int(years / 100) + int(years / 400)
```

@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def getDifference(dt1, dt2):
n1 = dt1.y * 365 + dt1.d

```
for i in range(0, dt1.m - 1):
    n1 += monthDays[i]

n1 += countLeapYears(dt1)

n2 = dt2.y * 365 + dt2.d
for i in range(0, dt2.m - 1):
    n2 += monthDays[i]
n2 += countLeapYears(dt2)
return n2 - n1
enter code here
```

pytest sample code:

import pytest
import calculateNoOfDays
from calculateNoOfDays import getDifference, Date
from tests.countNoOfDaysBetweenTheDates import *
from utilities.BaseClass import Configuration

@pytest.mark.parametrize('startdate, enddate, result',
[
(13 / 12 / 2018, 25 / 2 / 2019, 74),
(1 / 1 / 2004, 1 / 1 / 2005, 365)

```
                     ]
                     )
```

def test_dayCount(startdate, enddate, result):
assert calculateNoOfDays.getDifference(startdate, enddate) == result

But I am getting error in pytest result:
Output is:
plugins: html-3.1.1, metadata-1.11.0
collected 2 items

test_date.py::test_dayCount[0.000536835150313842-0.006191183754333828-74] FAILED                                 [ 50%]
test_date.py::test_dayCount[0.000499001996007984-0.0004987531172069825-365] FAILED                               [100%]

====================================================== FAILURES =======================================================
_____________________________ test_dayCount[0.000536835150313842-0.006191183754333828-74] _____________________________
Fixture "getDifference" called directly. Fixtures are not meant to be called directly,
but are created automatically when test functions request them as parameters.
See https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/fixture.html for more information about fixtures, and
https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/deprecations.html#calling-fixtures-directly about how to update your code.
____________________________ test_dayCount[0.000499001996007984-0.0004987531172069825-365] ____________________________
Fixture "getDifference" called directly. Fixtures are not meant to be called directly,
but are created automatically when test functions request them as parameters.
See https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/fixture.html for more information about fixtures, and
https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/deprecations.html#calling-fixtures-directly about how to update your code.
=============================================== short test summary info ===============================================
FAILED test_date.py::test_dayCount[0.000536835150313842-0.006191183754333828-74]
FAILED test_date.py::test_dayCount[0.000499001996007984-0.0004987531172069825-365]
================================================== 2 failed in 0.13s ==================================================

Can anyone help me how to fix the error?

Thanks
Pralay

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I'd expect `pytest` fixtures to be in the test file, not in the code under test. Methods decorated with `@pytest.fixture` are used by Pytest to generate values during test runs, and Pytest matches the names of the fixtures to the parameters in the methods under test. I think if you remove `@pytest.fixture(scope="class")` from `CalculateNoOfDays.py` you won't get this error any more.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `@pytest.fixture` decorator from `getDifference`.

The error message has helpful information about what the problem is, and how to fix it:

> Fixture "getDifference" called directly. Fixtures are not meant to be called directly, but are created automatically when test functions request them as parameters. See https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/fixture.html for more information about fixtures, and https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/deprecations.html#calling-fixtures-directly about how to update your code.

Pytest fixtures are passed as arguments to test functions, similar to `startdate, enddate, result` in your example. You don't add the decorator if you're calling it directly.

(The test still won't pass once you do this, but it'll be for a more useful reason: you're passing floats rather than instances of your `Date` class)